# Sierpinski Triangle: not displaying

Tags: java, swing

nothing is showing up at all..
I have tried moving Random rand = new Random() to outside of the loop, but it still doesnt work at all.
Nor does the frame exit on close.

```
public class myMain {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Frame frame = new Frame();
    }
}


public class Frame extends JFrame {

    public Frame(){
        super("Fancy Triangle");
        setSize(1024, 768);

        myPanel panel = new myPanel();
        add(panel);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

}

public class myPanel extends JPanel {

    int x1 = 512;

    int y1 = 109;

    int x2 = 146;
    int y2 = 654;

    int x3 = 876;
    int y3 = 654;

    int x = 512;
    int y = 382;

    int dx, dy;

    Random rand;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {

            g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            rand = new Random();
            int random = 1 + rand.nextInt(3);

            if (random == 1) {
                dx = x - x1;
                dy = y - y1;

            } else if (random == 2) {
                dx = x - x2;
                dy = y - y2;

            } else {
                dx = x - x3;
                dy = y - y3;

            }

            x = x - (dx / 2);
            y = y - (dy / 2);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you call `Thread.sleep` inside `paintComponent`?

Comment: Unrelated: please read about java naming conventions. Classes go CamelCase, but always starting Uppercase. Violating such conventions makes it harder for other people to read input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
Thread.sleep(300);
```

is not doing what you intend it to do. I think that you're trying to draw with a delay, but that's not what this does. Instead you're calling sleep on the Swing event thread puts the whole application to sleep, since the thread cannot do what it needs to do, including drawing the application and interacting with the user. Even worse, you're doing this within a painting method, a method that is required to be extremely fast since often the perceived responsiveness of a Swing application is determined by painting speed.

Instead use a Swing Timer ([Swing Timer tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)) to change the state of fields of the class, and then call repaint. Have your paintComponent use those changed fields to decide what to draw and where.  Since a Sierpinski triangle is composed of dots, consider creating an `ArrayList<Point>`, getting rid of the for loop inside your painting method, and using the Swing Timer to replace this for loop. Within the Timer's ActionListener, place the semi-random points into the ArrayList and call repaint. Then within paintComponent, iterate through the ArrayList, drawing each point that it contains.

Alternatively, you could draw the points onto a BufferedImage in your Swing Timer and then simply have your paintComponent display the BufferedImage via `g.drawImage(...)` method call. This would likely be more efficient.